# what is the right scope of login managed bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee

I have to create a @managedBean to manage thelogin/logout user,
what is the right scope of it?
@SessionScoped or @RequestScoped

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use @RequestScoped, so the bean will be quickly removed after login.  It is created upon a HTTP request and destroyed when the HTTP response is finished.

[The Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html)

[@RequestScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html)